# What is "login" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

I need to make sure the login button on a website is correct. I am of the opinion the following would be correct. I only speak basic Spanish. Which would be correct? Any other suggestions?

**Inicio de sesión / login**

Answer (score 10):

You can take a look at what some of the most popular sites are using for their Spanish versions:

- **Iniciar sesión** (Google, Facebook, Twitter, El País, El Mundo)
- **Acceder** (Wikipedia)
- **Ingresar** (Mercado Libre)
- **Identificarse** (Amazon)
- **Entrar** (La Caixa, Santander)

Comment: "Ingresar", while correct, is more widely used in Latin-American spanish.

Comment: The most real thing would be `Iniciar sesión`, but in web topics, it is more used to `Identificarse `

Answer (score -1):

You can use Login, the spanish speakers who will read it will understand.

Comment: Unless they are my mom.

Answer (score -5):

You could say : Registro or registrar.

Comment: *Registrar* would be the translation for "sign in", I think.

Comment: @MikMik registrar is sign up. Sign in is essentially equivalent to log in