# Uso de "-ar" vs "-ear" en la formación de barbarismos: "comitar" vs "comitear", "logar" vs "loguear"

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, sufijos, extranjerismos, neologismos

En muchas disciplinas, sobre todo técnicas, es habitual "castellanizar" vocablos extranjeros mediante el uso de sufijos.

Por ejemplo, en desarrollo de *software* tenemos los verbos ingleses *commit* para confirmar los cambios realizados en el código fuente, y *login* para la acción de identificarse ante un sistema.
Sin entrar en los porqués, en español lo normal no es decir ["confirmar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17811/13628) sino cosas como *"comitar"* o *"comitear"*. De la misma manera, también es muy corriente decir *"loguearse"* o *"logarse"* en vez de por ejemplo ["identificarse"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5770/13628).

Esto no es exclusivo del mundo de la programación. Se da también:

- en los videojuegos: *camp* - *"campear"*;
- en ingeniería de redes: *cap* - *"capar"*;
- en cualquier foro de internet: *post* - *"postear"*;
- y en general en cualquier actividad que tenga influencia del mundo anglosajón: *tune* - *"tunear"* en mecánica; *grind* - *"grindar"* en patinaje y ski, pero también *"grindear"* en póquer.

Ahora bien, como casi ninguna de estas palabras está reconocida por la RAE, y por tanto no hay una referencia sobre cuál es la versión correcta, hay diversidad de opiniones a la hora de formarlas: hay quien añade "-ar" al verbo extranjero, y hay quien añade "-ear" (tal como se ve en los ejemplos).

Supongamos por un momento que fuese correcto formar palabras de esta manera.
**¿Cuál sería el sufijo adecuado para castellanizar verbos extranjeros: "-ar" o "-ear"?**

Comment: Siempre escucho y utilizo *-ear* pero no sé por qué. Sospecho que es expresivo (como otros barbarismos). Buena pregunta. :)

Comment: Y ahora que lo pienso esos verbos nuevos siempre se construyen con la primera conjugación, nunca con -er o -ir, al menos no se me ocurre ninguno.

Comment: La primera conjugación es la única productiva en castellano (desde hace tiempo). https://www.delcastellano.com/productividad-linguistica/

Comment: [Muy relacionada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13323/12637). [Relacionada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19487/12637) pero menos.

Comment: Buenos hallazgos, @Charlie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La RAE reconoce el sufijo *[-ear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EIeaLdH)* como formador de "verbos derivados de sustantivos o adjetivos, rara vez de pronombres". Fundéu menciona este sufijo explícitamente como válido en las palabras [*mensajear* y *textear*](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/mensajear-mensajearse/), así como en otras derivadas directamente de extranjerismos, como *[wasapear](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/wasap-y-wasapear-grafias-validas/)*. Más allá de las adaptaciones fonéticas y ortográficas, no parece que la procedencia de la raíz represente ninguna diferencia.

El sufijo *-ear* tiene una [gran variedad de significados](http://www.sel.edu.es/pdf/ene-dic-07/RSEL-37-Martin.pdf) y es uno de los más frecuentes en la derivación a partir de sustantivos y adjetivos. Una vez que esto ocurre es natural que por analogía otras raíces lo adopten. En este punto "significa" bastante poco.

Sobre por qué se emplea un sufijo de derivación nominal con verbos extranjeros, hay que notar que en inglés (fuente de la inmensa mayoría de éstos) suele ocurrir que la misma raíz desnuda represente tanto un verbo como un sustantivo (*log* "bitácora", *post* "nota, envío", *camp* "campamento"), y que en castellano una raíz desnuda no es instintivamente reconocida por los hablantes como verbo. (Esto no implica que se la reconozca fácilmente como sustantivo; hay casos en que se deriva primero el verbo con *-ear* y luego se nominaliza con *-eo*, como en *el posteo* o *el logueo*.)

En cuanto a por qué este sufijo y no otro, ¿quién sabe? La primera conjugación es la única productiva (que admite crecimiento por incorporación de nuevos verbos) en castellano, y tal parece ser el caso desde hace mucho tiempo, con la excepción de algunos [verbos latinos de la segunda y tercera incorporados como cultismos](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/filoyletras/javel/productividad.pdf) (mayormente en la tercera).

Comment: No sabría decirte, porque jamás las he escuchado. Mis compañeros en desarrollo dicen *loguear, comitear, updatear*, etc., siempre con *-ear*.

Comment: «…de pronombres» --> *tutear*, *vosear*, *ustedear*

Comment: Yo sí oigo bastante *logar* aunque más loguear. Aparte de ese y *grindar* que ya lo ha dicho @walen no se me ocurre ningún otro que no acabe en *-ear*

Comment: Acabo de ver que han añadido en el DLE "clicar", otra más que acaba en *-ar* y no en *-ear*

Answer (score 3):

El gran desafío —tal vez irresoluble— de la etimología, más allá de descubrir la raíz de las palabras y cuál es su primer registro escrito, es —a mi modesto modo de ver— entender qué llevó a los hablantes a adoptar un modo de derivación en lugar de otro.

A la excelente [respuesta de pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23587/13628), sólo querría agregar que "-ear", además de reconocer la naturaleza nominal de la raíz, parece ser una desinencia más apropiada que "-ar" para:

1. crear una mayor distancia fonética de la raíz nominal anglosajona, que en todos los casos termina —como es típico del inglés— con un sonido consonántico final extraño al español: *surfear, plotear, zipear, deletear, setear, linkear, lookear*;
2. diferenciar estos verbos, muchos de los cuales tardarán —como es esperable— bastante tiempo en ser reconocidos por la RAE a pesar de su uso asiduo por parte de los hablantes, de otros con desinencia "-ar" ya existentes:

   - *testear* vs. *testar* (tachar, en la jerga legal);
   - *rapear* vs. *rapar*;
   - *topear* vs. *topar(se)*.

Comment: Uno de mis hijos inventó una palabra a los 4 años: *choferrear*.  La mamá tiene que choferrearlo para llegar a alguna parte.

Comment: @aparente001 Muy bueno. Eso demuestra la capacidad del hablante (en este caso, tu hijo) de extraer una regla de la lengua y aplicarla para crear una palabra. Los chicos son sabios y les cuesta reconocer excepciones.