# ¿Cuál es la traducción al español correcta del término "array"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Conocí el término "array" al estar aprendiendo C en el libro de Deitel y Deitel en el cual se mencionaba ***arreglo*** para referirse al término que en inglés se conoce como ***array***. Sin embargo, al estar dentro de la jerga de programación en español nunca veo que se utilice este término, sino ***vector*** o ***matriz*** de datos.

Al no ver el término utilizándose mas que en el libro quisiera saber cuál es la traducción correcta de *array*. El término se refiere a datos subsecuentes en memoria, a los cuales se puede acceder mediante un puntero que apunte al primer elemento y aritméticamente pueda acceder de uno en uno hasta el último elemento.

<sub>Pregunta basada en [esta entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/234718/2742) de StackOverflow en español.</sub>

Comment: Personalmente utilizo siempre array. Algunos enlaces útiles: 1. MDM web docs moz://a: la página en español acerca del [objeto Array de JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) 2. [php.net: Array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array.php)  Hice el mismo comentario aquí: [¿Es realmente “arreglo” una mala traducción (por semejanza) de “array”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/29069/es-realmente-arreglo-una-mala-traducci%C3%B3n-por-semejanza-de-array)

Comment: Considero que las palabras `vector` y `matriz` son inexactas y pueden crear confusión. Utilizo la palabra `vector` para describir y/o calcular la posición velocidad y aceleración como por ejemplo los vectores de [p5.js](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) . Utilizo `matriz` para calcular transformaciones vea `matriz de transformación`

Answer (score 11):

En 2013 pregunté a la [RAE](http://www.rae.es/) sobre la terminología que desde dicha institución consideraban adecuada para el lenguaje técnico en español. Mi pregunta no iba sobre el término *array* sino sobre la españolización de los términos *get*, *set* y *reset* como *getear*, *setear* y *resetear*, pero aunque su respuesta es en relación a esos términos, puede ser usada en la duda:

> En relación con su consulta, le remitimos la siguiente información:
>
> La cuestión es que si en español existen términos como *establecer*, *restablecer* y *obtener*, que son transparentes para quienes los emplean y no dejan lugar a dudas sobre su uso, no hay motivo para crear otros nuevos, como no lo hay para utilizar calcos del inglés, solo porque el  resultado de estos tenga alguna sílaba menos. Ahora bien, es cierto que el idioma pertenece a los hablantes, que son los responsables de su evolución histórica, pues lo van construyendo con su uso diario. De modo que son los especialistas de cada materia quienes tienen la oportunidad de asumir y difundir el empleo de determinadas voces y dejar al margen otras en las publicaciones de su especialidad.
>
> Reciba un cordial saludo
>
> ---
>
> Departamento de «Español al día» Real Academia Española

No creo que hayan cambiado de criterio en seis años, por lo que creo que la respuesta sigue siendo válida y aplicable en el contexto de tu duda:

**¿Cuál es la traducción al español correcta del término array?** La que nosotros como programadores popularicemos. Es muy frustrante buscar información sobre programación en el [segundo idioma más hablado del planeta (enero 2019)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Lenguas_por_n%C3%BAmero_de_hablantes_nativos) (por delante del inglés) y encontrar apenas nada. Los principales culpables de esto somos los programadores hispanohablantes, que no creamos contenido en nuestro idioma; para acabar con este problema debemos crear todo el contenido que podamos en nuestro idioma y hacer lo posible por popularizarlo, voy a listar (en orden alfabético) las palabras candidatas y mi opinión sobre las mismas... a partir de ahí, que gane la mejor:

- **Arreglo**: La más extendida hasta la fecha, personalmente no me gusta porque creo que en español (España) no transmite la idea de un conjunto de datos del mismo tipo con tamaño predefinido; parece más una traducción casi literal del término arr(ay|eglo).
- **Colección**: Un término que transmite muy bien la idea de conjunto de datos, pero no necesariamente transmite la idea de homogeneidad, personalmente me gusta bastante pero más para contenedores en general que para un tipo particular.
- **Formación**: En mi opinión, es la palabra que mejor transmite la idea de una colección de datos del mismo tipo con tamaño determinado de antemano ya que es muy fácil hacer la analogía con las formaciones *del mundo real* tanto de [una dimensión](http://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/image/file/34963/Optimized-DSC00415.JPG) como de [dos dimensiones](https://est.zetaestaticos.com/extremadura/img/noticias/1/118/1118831_1.jpg).
- **Matriz**: Una palabra adecuada para transmitir el concepto pero, que se puede confundir con el homónimo [matemático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_(matem%C3%A1ticas)) haciéndola inadecuada.
- **Vector**: Inadecuado porque se puede confundir con el homónimo [matemático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_vectorial).

Comment: Interesante, no se me había ocurrido "formación" como alternativa. ¡Bienvenido al sitio!

Comment: @Charlie es un término que estoy intentando popularizar :)

Comment: Entiendo, el problema que le veo es precisamente ese matiz militar del término. De hecho el DLE [define esa acepción](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IF1I1Br) como de uso solo en el ámbito militar. También se usa en la política ("formación política"), y por estos usos precisamente no creo que se llegue a popularizar en la informática, pero eres libre de intentarlo. :-) Personalmente a "arreglo" no le veo problema dado que "arreglar" significa "componer, ordenar". No creo que sea una mala traducción de "array". Podría ser una pregunta interesante.

Comment: @Charlie "*son los especialistas de cada materia quienes tienen la oportunidad de asumir y difundir el empleo de determinadas voces*", palabra de RAE ;P de la misma manera que "formación" puede tener significados diferentes en educación y política, en programación se puede (intentar) popularizar para referirse a "elementos iguales organizados de una manera". Por otro lado ¿habrías pensado en el matiz militar si hubiese escogido [otra foto](http://files.errepan.coriweb.it/webpages/0/1/0_big.jpg) de ejemplo?

Comment: Sobre _setear_, _resetear_, etc, puedes leer [Uso de “-ar” vs “-ear” en la formación de barbarismos: “comitar” vs “comitear”, “logar” vs “loguear”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23585/1674)

Comment: Sí que había pensado en el matiz militar antes de ver las fotos, pero insisto en que eres libre de intentar popularizar "formación". De hecho, acabo de descubrir que la palabra "array" se introdujo en el inglés en el siglo XIV, y por entonces se usaba precisamente con el significado de "fila de soldados, tropas en formación", y acabó siendo usada sencillamente como "ordenación" a principios del XIX. Menos mal que hoy en día los cambios suceden muchísimo más rápido. :-)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, coincido en que _arreglo_ no transmite la idea porque parece más una traducción por semejanza. Me ha sorprendido tu comentario acerca de que es la más extendida; nunca había leído _arreglo_ como _array_ antes.

Comment: @Ra_ Doy fe de que se usa "arreglo" en entornos académicos. Al menos se usaba a finales del siglo pasado. :-)

Comment: @walen no he añadido **array** por estar buscando, precisamente, alternativas a dicha palabra :P

Comment: Matrices y vectores me parecen apropiadas e incluso dan mas información que _array_ ya que expresan de una vez si se habla de una entidad de una o más dimensiones.

Comment: ¿Y qué tal "tabla" como traducción libre de "array"? Las tablas expresan conjuntos de elementos, con un cierto orden, o posicionamiento, fisicamente contiguos, como en las tablas "físicas". Lo que no sé es si queda claro el tema de la homogeneidad en este caso.

Comment: "*Tabla*" transmite (al menos a mi) una idea de bidimensionalidad (filas y columnas) por lo que no sería adecuada para transmitir la idea de un conjunto de datos homogéneos de una sola dimensión.