# ¿Es realmente "arreglo" una mala traducción (por semejanza) de "array"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, vocabulario-técnico, inglés

En la pregunta *[¿Cuál es la traducción al español correcta del término "array"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29066/12637)* se ha comentado que la opción *arreglo*, supuestamente de uso mayoritario a la hora de traducir la voz inglesa *array*, es o parece una mala traducción de esta, debido a la semejanza.

¿Lo es realmente?

Según [la web de etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/array#etymonline_v_41458), la voz *array* proviene del francés, y antes del latín vulgar **ar-redare*. En el siglo XIV significaba en inglés "fila de soldados" o "tropas en formación", dando origen en el siglo XIX a su significado como "disposición ordenada".

En cuanto a *arreglo*, Corominas afirma que es un derivado de *regla*, del latín *regŭla*, 'regla, barra de metal o madera'. Luego "arreglar" sería "disponer conforme a una regla", lo que daría a *arreglo* su acepción como "regla, orden, coordinación". La voz *arreglo* se introduce en el español en el siglo XVIII con este sentido. De hecho la acepción anteriormente mencionada se encuentra en el DLE desde 1803.

Sin embargo, y por profundizar un poco más, ¿qué era realmente un arreglo en el español del siglo XVIII? ¿Significaba algo que sugiriese una "disposición ordenada" de elementos, como en un *array*? ¿Algo parecido a las formaciones militares pero con objetos en vez de soldados?

La idea es saber si *arreglo* es o no una mala traducción de *array*, y para eso quería saber si los significados se asemejan, e incluso saber si incluso la palabra española adquirió su significado antes que la inglesa.

Comment: A mi si me parece una mala traducción. **Matrices** y **vectores** me parecen apropiadas e incluso dan mayor información que _array_ ya que expresan de una vez si se habla de una entidad de una o más dimensiones. En algunos casos que un desarrollador distingue fácilmente, los vectores pueden intercambiarse por **listas**

Comment: Personalmente utilizo siempre `array`. Algunos enlaces útiles: **1**. MDM web docs moz://a: la página en español acerca del [objeto **Array** de JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) **2**. [php.net: Array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array.php)

Comment: Creo que en general, dependerá del idioma, ya que cada término en inglés puede variar su significado. Pero por lo menos (que nunca había caído en su significado antiguo) no me es mala, sobre todo si hay que hacer alguna distinción con otras clases/conceptos parecidos. (Por ejemplo, en Perl 6 h existen secuencias, listas, pero Array y Hash, los dos podrían aceptar fácilmente arreglo como traducción, pero solo matriz serviría para la primera por lo que arreglo sería mejor para Hash (que es un tipo de diccionario/arreglo asociado)

Answer (score 7):

Si *arreglo* es mala traducción o no termina siendo asunto de opinión, pero intentaré fundamentarla en razón de los significados de *arreglo* y de sus palabras relacionadas, y las asociaciones que despierta en los hablantes.

*Arreglo*, *arreglar*, *regla*, *reglar*, *regular*, *regulación*, etc. se refieren todas a diferentes aspectos de orden, coordinación, buen comportamiento, buena apariencia o corrección. En mi dialecto decimos *arreglar* por *reparar* y *arreglo* por *reparación* (de un vehículo o una máquina, por ejemplo, o para referirnos a un empaste dental). También se dice *arreglo* como sinónimo de *acuerdo*, con la connotación de "solución de un conflicto". Una *regla* (el instrumento recto) puede servir para poner cosas en fila, pero en general la pensamos más como un instrumento para medir y marcar distancias *regulares*. Decimos *poner en regla* con el sentido de "ordenar, formalizar, acomodar, emprolijar"; no lo relacionamos inmediatamente con una disposición física o abstracta de tipo vectorial (ahí decimos más bien *poner en fila*). Cuando alguien *se arregla* lo que hace es acomodarse los cabellos, vestirse bien y limpio, etc.; no es que se acomoda físicamente en un lugar o dentro de una estructura.

Fuera de la profesión informática *arreglo* no se relaciona con una disposición de objetos de un tipo determinado. Puede ocurrir que pensemos en un *arreglo* de cosas como grupo bien dispuesto, pero no como en una fila o matriz. Un *ikebana* es una forma de lo que llamamos *arreglo floral*; es un orden deliberado pero asimétrico. Cuando hablamos de *arreglar* algo estamos más cerca de pensarlo como una cuestión de armonía (estética o funcional) que de orden físico (una disposición de mínima entropía).

Por todo lo anterior creo que *arreglo* es una mala traducción de *array*, y que deberíamos buscar otra palabra para designar este tipo de estructuras de datos, o bien resignarnos al anglicismo crudo, que por otra parte no requiere de mucha adaptación fonética.

Comment: no creo que sea una mala traduccion: tambien se refiere a las reglas, ordenamientos o coordinaciones , por ejemplo: arreglo musical

Answer (score 1):

Cuando un lenguaje de programación tiene la capacidad de manejar variables de tipo **arreglo** (o **array**) se refiere a que puede construir y manipular variables con subíndice.

En informática **matrices**, **vectores** y **listas** se refieren a objetos o entidades diferentes y no son intercambiables.

Si una variable de tipo **arreglo** es de 1 dimensión, entonces se asimila al concepto matemático de  **vector**.

Si una variable de tipo **arreglo** es de 2 o más dimensiones, entonces  se asimila al concepto matemático de **matriz**.

Respecto a las **[listas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_enlazada)** en informática se refiere una **[estructura de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estructura_de_datos)**, que es una secuencia de nodos unidos por punteros o enlaces al siguiente nodo o al anterior nodo.
Algunos lenguajes de programación permiten crear variables de tipo **lista**.
En otros lenguajes hay que usar variables de tipo **arreglo** para simular el comportamiento de una **lista**.

Es por todo esto que la palabra **arreglo** está extendida y de uso aceptado en la documentación en español que tenga que ver con el concepto informático de **array**.

Ejemplo de documentación:

[Todo sobre como declarar un arreglo en c++](https://postparaprogramadores.com/como-declarar-un-arreglo-en-c/)

Comment: Interesante; yo soy programador y nunca había ni usado ni escuchado arreglo referido a array; he visto documentación pero incluso esta es residual; alguien utiliza arreglo en su día a día de programador?

Comment: @Ramon Ud. es de cuál país? En Colombia usamos la palabra **arreglo** .
ejemplo: [Cómo declarar un arreglo en C++](https://postparaprogramadores.com/como-declarar-un-arreglo-en-c/)

Comment: Matrices, vectores o listas nos dan la idea de **dimensión**, (2, 1 y 1). Cuando hay más de dos dimensiones necesitamos indicarlo, matrices multidimensionales, e incluso disponemos de matrices irregulares. **Arreglo, no nos ofrece la idea de dimensión**.